# Laravel 8 Redirect back with message not working in blade template

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am using Laravel v8.16.1 and PHP v7.3.1 when I am trying to get a message in the blade template.

```
@if(session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h5><i class="icon fas fa-ban"></i> Success!</h5>
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Using the below code, it's working for me.

```
$req->session()->flash('error', 'Invalid Username or Password');
return view('admin.views.login');
```

However, it's not the right way, and when I am trying to redirect back using the below code, then it's not working

```
return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Invalid Username or Password');
```

Please help what is missing or what is wrong?

Comment: You are passing `error` session, but displaying `success` session?

Comment: it was just type mistake i edited question and set error instead of success, but code is not working @HTMHell

Comment: If you mixed up your session var names, maybe they are still mixed up in your view cache.  Try clearing that with `php artisan view:clear`.  You should also edit your question to fix the typo, to avoid confusing every other person trying to help.

Comment: i tried php artisan view:clear but still not working @Don'tPanic

Comment: I had the same issue. In my case it was a conflict with a JavaScript plugin called touchswipe. removing that  plugin solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use to show errors

```
@if(count($errors) > 0 )
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="p-0 m-0" style="list-style: none;">
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <li>{{$error}}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

And the redirect code would be

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['errors' => 'There is some error in the details.']);
```

Comment: Are you using any cache?

Comment: not sure, it's default laravel installation, and i am learning laravel